# "Cannot prove" when converting list of lists to a Map

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have a stubborn error in my Scala code, faithfully reproduced below. In reduceDataToMap, I would like to iterate through the first dimension of someData.data (ie, the rows) and put those as the values in a Map, which has the column headers as the keys.

```
object Test {

  type Header = String
  type DataObj = Int
  type ReducedRow = Map[Header, DataObj]

  case class SomeData(
    dataCols: List[Header],
    data: List[List[DataObj]]
  )

  def reduceDataToMap(someData: SomeData): List[ReducedRow] = {
    someData.data.map(row => List(someData.dataCols, row).toMap
    )
  }
}
```

Instead it spits out the error:

```
Cannot prove that List[Any] <:< (K, V).
```

It sounds as though the compiler has failed to infer the type of the actual elements in someData.data, and so isn't sure if they can constitute a Map value? But I'm really guessing here and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: No, the compiler is fine. But it seems you are still pretty new to language. I would suggest you to keep following any tutorial or book, and check the scaladoc: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

Comment: Thanks - and yes you are correct that I am new to the language. So the lesson here, I guess, is that the compiler will only permit a map to be created in this way if it can confirm that the list of keys and the list of values are of the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below creates the list of two elements

```scala
List(someData.dataCols, row)
```

If `dataCols` and inner `data` lists have the same size you can `zip` this lists:

```scala
someData.data.map(row => someData.dataCols.zip(row).toMap)
```